# How do I intercept the constructor for a Swift class using Frida?

Tags: ios, swift, frida

I am attempting to use the frida swift bridge functionality built into Frida to hook the constructor of a Swift class. I am running my code with the command:

```
frida --no-pause -U -l swift_cooperia.js -f com.example.myapp
```

with the contents of swift_cooperia.js being:

```
Swift.Interceptor.attach(Swift.classes.hooked_class.init, {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log("obj instantiated");
    }
});
```

I am trying to use the Swift.Interceptor.Attach function, but I'm not quite sure what to use for the first argument (the function I'm trying to hook). In all of the examples I've seen of the interceptor, I *should* be using something like Swift.classes.hooked_class.init (what I'm doing right now in my swift_cooperia.js file) for my first argument, but this throws the following error:

```
Error: missing argument
    at T (frida/node_modules/frida-swift-bridge/dist/lib/macho.js:144)
    at F (frida/node_modules/frida-swift-bridge/dist/lib/macho.js:155)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-swift-bridge/dist/lib/interceptor.js:23)
    at <eval> (/swift_cooperia.js:5)
```

I have also tried using Swift.classes.hooked_class.init() but this errors with:

```
TypeError: not a function
    at <eval> (/swift_cooperia.js:1)
```

I have also tried Swift.classes.hooked_class.init.implementation which errors with:

```
TypeError: cannot read property 'implementation' of undefined
    at <eval> (/swift_cooperia.js:1)
```

When I look at the $methods properties of the class using Swift.class.hooked_class during a frida session (not in this script execution), I get the following:

```
"$methods": [
        {
            "address": "0x1008e37b8",
            "type": "Method"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x1008e3b90",
            "type": "Method"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x1008e5998",
            "type": "Method"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x1008e5e30",
            "type": "Method"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x1008e5e50",
            "type": "Method"
        }
    ]
```

Which shows no easy constructor or init method. One of these might be the init method, but I have no clue how to sniff out which one is, if any, and after that how to use it as the first parameter for the Swift Interceptor.
I'm very new to using Frida, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To identify the method you may print the module base address using Frida to get the method addresses in the binary (get rid of the ASLR offset). Then decompile the binary using a  tool like Ghidra or IDA and check the addresses to which method they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frida Swift bridge author here. The method you're trying to hook isn't symbolicated which is why the bridge can't intercept it, from the [docs](https://github.com/frida/frida-swift-bridge/blob/master/docs/api.md):

> A major caveat is that the function at target has to have a Swift symbol or either we bail. The symbol is required for the parsing of argument and return types.

The API should be returning a more useful error though, so I'll fix that.

(Also feel free to open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/frida/frida-swift-bridge/issues) as it'll get much better coverage there, I came across this by chance!)